# TeamCity CI deployment is not working properly for Umbraco websites

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, umbraco, teamcity-9.0

I am using teamcity for CI.

TeamCity works perfectly for .NET projects and It's component.
When I try to deploy my Umbraco code from Dev environment to UAT - Changes which are done from Umbraco Admin panel are not getting reflected or deployed.

Here are things which I am deploying using Teamcity :

1. Database
2. API
   and last
3. Umbraco Website

But I am not able to see the Umbraco admin changes.

Any idea ? 
Mostly there is no way to commit code which updated from Umbraco Admin.

Please help me, If anyone have idea ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how you are deploying your website / database using TeamCity?

Comment: I am using MSbuild runner to build the website code and database.

Comment: So do you have an SSDT project for the database? Is all of your data under source control? How are you deploying this?

Comment: Are you deploying the current Dev Database to UAT? If not, it won't have the changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

I also use TeamCity for Umbraco CI.  The basic premise I would use would be to move code forward (dev -> staging -> uat -> live) & move data, copy, images backwards.

I've never had much success with automatically moving umbraco metadata forwards whether using Courier or database changesets.  To this day the only safe way (in my opinion) to promote umbraco admin changes is to redo them manually each time in the next environment along.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your feedback.